# use of if condition in a chat box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just don't know how to use IF condition here i use bubble chat too ,so when the textfield is empty the bubble chat gets updated without any texts.i don't want it.So how to use IF condition for it properly.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").focus();
  };
  function typo(){
   var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;
  var z = document.getElementById('demo');
  z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
  }
 var input = document.getElementById("myText");
 input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  document.getElementById("btn-chat").click();
  }
  });
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
        <div class="btn-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="bottom">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input class="widebox" type="text" id="myText" value="">
    <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkjbryqe/6/) here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to make sure there is at least a length of 1 char.

After looking at your demo you added, you can also make sure white space is gone by using trim() to check.

```
if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value.trim().length > 0) {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkjbryqe/8/

Comment: But when i click the send button, the bubble still appears.

Comment: @Chrisstewart please post me a link to your latest fiddle

Answer (score 0):

`if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value.length)`... could work?

Comment: Sir ! i posted my demo in fiddle below my question ..am new to coding can you please tell me in fiddle thank you for the contribution and time

Answer (score 0):

i posted a demo in fiddle below my question ..So that i can be more clear of what am doing and thanks everyone for the time to look through my question and helping me out.I really appreciate

Comment: I added your demo to my answer @chris stewart. please check it out and if it helps don't foget to up vote and mark as answer. best of luck to you on your coding journey!

Comment: When i use the send button,the empty bubble still appears